# Python Dictionary to URL Parameters

Tags: python, dictionary, url-parameters

I am trying to convert a Python dictionary to a string for use as URL parameters. I am sure that there is a better, more [Pythonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythonic) way of doing this. What is it?

```
x = ""
for key, val in {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}.items():
    x += "%s=%s&" %(key,val)
x = x[:-1]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the correct way of using it in Python 3.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
params = {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
print(urlencode(params))
```

Comment: Since python 2 is now deprecated I would accept this answer but stack overflow is preventing me from changing the accepted answer.

Comment: How is this different from my answer which was ~ a year earlier before this one?

Answer (score 319):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode). It takes a dictionary of key-value pairs, and converts it into a form suitable for a URL (e.g., `key1=val1&key2=val2`).

For your example:

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> params = {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
'a=A&b=B'
```

If you want to make a URL with repetitive params such as: `p=1&p=2&p=3` you have two options:

```
>>> a = (('p',1),('p',2), ('p', 3))
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode(a)
'p=1&p=2&p=3'
```

or:

```
>>> urllib.parse.urlencode({'p': [1, 2, 3]}, doseq=True)
'p=1&p=2&p=3'
```

If you are still using Python 2, use [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode).

Comment: if you want to make a url with repetitive params for example: ?p=1&p=2&p=3 then a = (('p',1),('p',2), ('p', 3)); urllib.urlencode(a) the result is 'p=1&p=2&p=3'

Comment: Another way to get repetitive params: urllib.urlencode({'p': [1, 2, 3]}, doseq=True) resulting in 'p=1&p=2&p=3'.

Comment: If you wonder what `doeseq` is about: "If any values in the query arg are sequences and doseq is true, each  sequence element is converted to a separate parameter."

Comment: Python3 users: `urllib.parse.urlencode()`

Answer (score 41):

For python 3, the `urllib` library has changed a bit, now you have to do:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode


params = {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}

urlencode(params)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the 3rd party Python url manipulation library **furl**:

```
f = furl.furl('')
f.args = {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}
print(f.url) # prints ... '?a=A&b=B'
```

If you want repetitive parameters, you can do the following:

```
f = furl.furl('')
f.args = [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'),('b', 'B2')]
print(f.url) # prints ... '?a=A&b=B&b=B2'
```

Comment: Where do I get furl? It appears not to be a standard library

Comment: `pip install furl` Its not a part of standard library

Answer (score -11):

This seems a bit more Pythonic to me, and doesn't use any other modules:

```
x = '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in {'a':'A', 'b':'B'}.items()])
```

Comment: This won't percent encode the parameters properly. This will create unexpected results if your data includes ampersands, equals, hash symbols, etc.